# When creating remote BLOB store is "RBSFilestreamFile" always the name of the file to be added to the FILEGROUP?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When creating a remote BLOB store in SQL Server (2008 R2) is "RBSFilestreamFile" always the name of the file when adding it to the FILEGROUP like in this query (this is the name I've seen used in every example I've found online, but I need to know for sure)?

```
ADD FILE (name = RBSFilestreamFile, filename = 'c:\Blobstore')
    TO FILEGROUP RBSFilestreamProvider
```

I'm asking because I'm working on an application for restoring SharePoint content databases and need to know if I can hardcode this string into the application.

I know you can create file groups and files with any name you want, but specifically for setting up RBS with SharePoint using SQL 2008's built in FILESTREAM provider are these names an expected convention? i.e. Will it work if I name my FILEGROUP and/or FILE something else?

Answer (score 1):

The filename and filegroup name are not fixed.

SharePoint will use the same name when creating the databases.  However there's nothing that would prevent someone from changing those names to something else if they desired.  I'd query for them from the database backup using RESTORE FILELISTONLY then create the RESTORE DATABASE Command based off that information.

Comment: Please see updated question, this doesn't entirely help.